# How to properly send a request to a web server which processes some data and sends a file back

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, request

Basically I'm trying to make an  app which requires certain operation be made on a remote server (in order to avoid using a large amount of internet data). So what I'm thinking is that I should send a http request to a server, wait for it to process it and then recevive a file back. One way of doing this is by sending an id (depending on what I want to process) within the url and access it on the server with php using $_GET. However I'm asking myself if this is the proper way of doing this. Can't the server be flooded with too many requests easily if it's address is somehow found? What are the other alternatives, what technolgies should I use and where should I start reading about it?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I have a misunderstanding about what I've just written, still trying to figure all these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use something like queue service , For that [GearMan](http://gearman.org/) is the best solution.

Basically you can setup the German server and send all the request to the server and write the workers which will do the processing. ITs completely distributed system and all things will be done in the backend so that no one will able to call it via HTTP. Since this workers don't need to be on the HTTP server so you can disable it for public so it can be more secure.